# Password field in lock screen loses focus

Tags: gnome, 22.04, suspend, mouse, password

Sometimes when I wake up the computer after suspend, I notice that the password field loses focus while I am typing the password. I am unable to move the focus by pressing tab. The only way is to use the mouse to click on the field. Is there any suggestion why this happens? There seems to be some [record](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4858) of other users experiencing similar issue. Does this have issue have a solution?

Comment: Are you touching the TouchPad?

Comment: No I am not. I use a RF connected keyboard and mouse.